# Proper usage of HTML5 elements & structure

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I need to convert a PSD to HTML5/CSS. I'm having problems finding a definitive answer on what elements to use. My layout consists of a header, content/sidebar and footer. The template structure is below.

I understand you can use multiple header / footer elements with HTML5, I've got the main header/footer tags. The main problem I'm having is with the structure of the content.

I've got a main content area, and then a sidebar, the sidebar content doesn't really relate to the content. Within the sidebar I need to have multiple content boxes.

The content area has various sections, mainly a featured image with text on, and then the rest is just the page text.

From what I understand, using the `<section>` tag to define the content / sidebar isn't semantic as it's not content related, it's page structure / layout. Does my markup below look correct for the structure I'm trying to achieve?

```
    <header>

    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <section id="featured-content">
                <img />
                <p>Featured text</p>
            </section>

            <section id="main">
                <header><h2>Title</h2></header>
                <p>The rest of content goes here</p>
            </section>
        </div>

        <aside class="sidebar">
            <section class="content-box">
                <header>Box title</header>
                <p>Box content</p>
            </section>

            <section class="content-box">
                <header>Box title</header>
                <p>Box content</p>
            </section>
        </aside>
    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>`
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Are `#featured-content` and `#main` related somehow? What is the role of the featured content? A real example could help here. 2) And could you include all headings (`h1`-`h6`) you use? (Or is the `h2` the only one?)

Comment: Yes - they're related. Within the `#main` is the page content, the #featured-content is almost a summary of the page content. Looking further into HTML5 elements, I think I should be replacing `#main` with `<main>`, then within that element, have `<article>` for the actual page content, within that, for the featured element, use `<section id="featured">` and then use `<aside>` for the sidebar?

Comment: Although - looking at some other articles, apparently <aside> should be used for the content boxes? Or - within <aside> as my sidebar, should I then use <section class="box"> or similar?

Comment: Something like this? http://pastebin.com/DKwtEmJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: If the `header` only contains a heading, you could omit it.

If the main content of the page could stand on its own (e.g. like a blog post or similar), then you could use `article` instead of `section`.

As the `#featured-content` is some kind of abstract/summary of the main content, it should be part of the `article`. It makes sense to include it in the `header`:

```
<article>

  <header>
    <h2>(article title)</h2>

    <img src="" alt="(article teaser image)">
    <p>(article teaser text)</p>
  </header>

  <p>(article content)</p>

</article>
```

(Only if the teaser is really complex (e.g. containing headings itself), it could get its own `section`.)

Using `aside` for the sidebar is correct, because its content is "tangentially related" to the whole page (!) and not only to the main content (in that case, it should be include in the `article`, too).

If all content blocks in that `aside` are somewhat related, using `section` inside of that `aside` for each block is correct (but, depending on the actual content, `article` could be appropriate, also). However, if the blocks inside of that `aside` have no relation (easy test: do you find a heading for the whole `aside`?), you could consider using a separate `aside` for each of it:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <aside>
    <h2>…</h2>
  </aside>

  <aside>
    <h2>…</h2>
  </aside>
</div>
```

So the structure could look like:

```
<body>
  <h1>…</h1> <!-- maybe with header -->

  <article>
    <h2>…</h2>
  </article>

  <aside> 
    <h2>…</h2> <!-- omit it or hide it visually -->

    <section> <!-- or article -->
      <h3>…</h3>
    </section>

    <section> <!-- or article -->
      <h3>…</h3>
    </section> 

  </aside> <!-- resp. use 1 aside for each block -->

  <footer></footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Cheers, thankfully this is very similar to what I went with in the end. I'm using `<section>` within the `<aside>` as the content is only a couple of lines for each, after a bit of research I don't think article is suitable.

On your comment for the heading tag in the `<aside>`, when running my code through the HTML5 outliner, I was getting the undefined section thing, is this for the purpose of that (and I assume some other purpose I'm not aware of, SEO?). Can I just put `<h2>Sidebar</h2>` or something similar and hide it in the CSS?

Comment: @RyanPilbeam: *Each* sectioning element (`section`, `article`, `aside`, `nav`) produces an entry in the document outline. If you provide headings inside of a sectioning element, it simply takes the first one. If you don’t provide any headings, it creates a "undefined" entry. Now, it’s valid to not specify any heading explictly (often not advisable, but there are some cases where it’s appropriate). And you could also specify one and hide it visually, so that it is still read to screen reader users.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. On the outliner the first section is empty, should the site name be a `<h1>` in the main `<header>` element?

Comment: @RyanPilbeam: Yes, the site name should be `h1` (whether in `header` or not). So all following headings and sectioning elements are in scope of this site heading.